# Redirect stdout to logger in Python

Tags: python, logging, stdout

Can I redirect all output from `stdout` to a logger I have set up with the standard `logging` module?
(I have os.system calls whose output I'd also like to see or occational print statements)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975248/redirecting-sys-stdout-to-python-logging

Comment: Thanks! Somehow the automatic suggestions only showed stdout redirection to files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to make use of the suggestion in [this post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-treat-logger-like-output-stream.html), summarised below:

```
import logging

class LoggerWriter:
    def __init__(self, logger, level):
        self.logger = logger
        self.level = level

    def write(self, message):
        if message != '\n':
            self.logger.log(self.level, message)

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger("demo")
    info_fp = LoggerWriter(logger, logging.INFO)
    debug_fp = LoggerWriter(logger, logging.DEBUG)
    print >> info_fp, "An INFO message"
    print >> debug_fp, "A DEBUG message"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When run, the script prints:

```
INFO:demo:An INFO message
DEBUG:demo:An DEBUG message
```